# Find the probability that Q gets the larger share pf the land.

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

The mukhiya of the village of rampur couldn't solve the 40 year old land dispute case. The disputed land was 100 km² in size. Person P and  and person Q both were claiming the emtire land. In the end, the mukhiya decided to arbitrarily divide the land between P and Q. Surprisingly, both of them agreed. But person Q had bribed the mukhiya with a promise of the 20% of price of land if he received the larger  one. Find the probability that Q gets twice as much as P or more.

My approach:-
Let $x$ be the size of land that Q receives and $y$ be the size of land that P receives. Then $x+y=100$.
Also, if the size of land that Q receives is twice or more as much as P then,
$$x\geq 2y$$
i.e
$$3x\geq 200$$
Which means that
$$x\geq \frac{200}{3}$$
So this means that $$\frac{200}{3}\leq x\leq 100$$.
So probability that Q gets bigger= $\frac{100-\frac{200}{3}}{100}$=$\frac{1}{3}$

Is the above solution correct? If not please let me know the correct way to approach this problem. Also, is the data about bribing relevant in this question? Please Help. Thank you

Comment: This is hard to follow.  First of all, probabilities can't be greater than $1$.  Secondly, are we to understand that the adjudicator pockets the bribe but nevertheless apportions the land uniformly at random?  Strange sort of bribe.  But if that's what you want to assume, you should at least spell it out explcitly.

Comment: What is the probability space?  Questions of probability are meaningless unless the mechanism of choice is known.

Comment: @lulu , sorry that was a typo. I jave edited accordingly.

Comment: Should add:  I agree with the answer $\frac 13$ under the assumption that we are ignoring the bribe entirely, and the land is being divided uniformly at random.

Comment: @saulspatz, Since Q must receive greater than $\frac{200}{3}$ so the space in favour of Q would be $100-\frac{100}{3}$. I'm only confused about the universal space. I'm unable to understand if the data about bribing the mukhiya is relevant or not

Comment: @lulu do you think the data about bribing is relevant?

Comment: To stress:  the entire problem hinges on the manner in which the land is being divided.  The answer $\frac 13$ is correct under the assumption that a number, $x\in [0,1]$ is uniformly chosen to represent the portion of land awarded to $Q$.  This assumption ignores the bribe entirely.  Nothing in the problem statement gives us a hint as to how the bribe mind alter the process.  We could make various things up, but it would just be idle speculation.

Comment: @lulu Thanks a lot!!